# Text won't display in Processing

Tags: processing

Im on sketchpad.cc, and draw method won't output any text.

```java
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
int x1 = 0; int y1 = 0; int x2 = 0; int y2 = 0; int x3 = 0; int y3 = 0; 
void setup() {  // this is run once.   

    // set the background color
    background(255);


    // canvas size (Integers only, please.)
    size(300, 300); 

    // smooth edges
    smooth();

    // limit the number of frames per second
    frameRate(30);

    strokeWeight(2); 

} 

void mouseClicked() {
  if(count == 0) {
    x1 = mouseX;
    y1 = mouseY;
    count++;
  }
  if(count == 1) {
    x2 = mouseX;
    y2 = mouseY;
    line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    count++;
  }
  if(count == 2) {
    x3 = mouseX;
    y3 = mouseY;
    count = 0;
    line (x1, y1, x2, y2);
    line (x2, y2, x3, y3);
    line (x3, y3, x1, y1);
  }

}

void draw() {
line (40,50,40,90);
text("derp",10,50);
text(x1+","+y1+","+x2+","+y2+","+x3+","+y3, 10, 20);
}
```

The program is supposed to draw triangles. My draw method will draw the line like its supposed it, but it won't do the text. The thing that makes me frustrated, is that I have used text() before with no issues. I went back and loaded another program I made before with text(), and it works just fine! Printing text n everything. But my current program won't do it.

Im so lost :(

Answer (score 1):

Please narrow you problem down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting. For example, this much smaller program shows the same problem as your full sketch:

```
void setup() {  
  size(300, 300); 
  background(255);
} 

void draw() {
  text("derp", 10, 50);
}
```

If you run this program, you'll just see a white background, even though we're calling the `text()` function. To debug this, I'd start by taking out the call to `background()` and running that.

```
void setup() {  
  size(300, 300); 
} 

void draw() {
  text("derp", 10, 50);
}
```

If you run that program, you'll see that the text is drawn to the screen, and it's drawn in white. That's because the default draw color is white. So the first program is just drawing white text on top of a white background, which is why you can't see it.

To fix the problem, either change the background color or change the text color using the `fill()` function.

Another piece of advice: you need to work in smaller chunks. Instead of writing your entire program and then wondering why it doesn't work, you need to get one small piece working at a time. Work in chunks like the examples in this post, and only add small bits of code when everything is working perfectly. That will help you catch errors like this one. Recommended reading: [How to Program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program)

Answer (score 1):

(I know this question is old but for anyone else having this problem)

If you put `fill(0)` (or whatever color you want) in `draw()`, the text will appear. To make the text less fuzzy, move `background(255)` to `draw()` as well, but **before** `fill(0)`. If you set the background after `fill(0)` the text won't be visible.

For some reason, if you set the background in `setup()` instead of `draw()`, the text is fuzzier.

```
// variables

void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  smooth();
  frameRate(30);
  strokeWeight(2);

void mouseClicked() {
  // function

void draw() {
  // set background color
  background(255);

  line (40, 50, 40, 90);
  text("derp", 10, 50);
  text(x1+","+y1+","+x2+","+y2+","+x3+","+y3, 10, 20);

  fill(0);
}
```